# how to export PowerShell to CSV

Tags: powershell, office365

i have the below powershell code

- not the best

it shows the owners names then lists the members of a FL group

```
$DGName = "NAME OF O365 DL"
>> Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGName -ResultSize unlimited | Select ManagedBy, PrimarySMTPAddress
>> Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DGName -ResultSize Unlimited | Select Name, PrimarySMTPAddress
```

is there a way to export this to a excel CSV.

also, im wondering how to i show the owners email address as it only popualtes the names

Comment: Try to add " | Out-File -Append C:\FolderPath\myFile.csv -Encoding UTF8" at the end of your command

Comment: I get a csv with

"ï»¿" in cell A1

Comment: [1] save each of the `Get-*` command results to a $Var. [2] iterate thru the 2nd $Var. [3] use the 1st $Var and the current iteration values to build a `[PSCustomObject]`. [4] send that out to a $Collection. [5] send that collection to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you need to add in a `Export-Csv` for instance

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGName -ResultSize unlimited | Export-Csv -Path .\distgrp.csv| Select ManagedBy, PrimarySMTPAddress
```

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DGName -ResultSize Unlimited | Export-Csv -Path .\distgrpmbr.csv| Select Name, PrimarySMTPAddress
```

NB: I've not tried this, but in principle, it should work.

For the second part, I'm not sure this is possible reading the docs on the methods you're using. There may be another method for this.

Comment: when i run the command i get


cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Comment: then i get a blank report

Comment: Shouldn't the Export-Csv command be preceded by a pipeline character?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Edited to add `|`. Thanks both.

Comment: @SSP did you get it working?